# Vue3 import props from another file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue3 with the options API. I have several vue components which use this prop:

```
  exercise: {
    type: Object as PropType<Exercise>,
    required: true,
  },
```

So I decided to create a `sharedProps` object which contains it in order to import it (and any other shared prop) inside the components, without having to define the same prop multiple times:

```
export const sharedProps = {
  exercise: {
    type: Object as PropType<Exercise>,
    required: true,
  },
```

However, if I import it and use inside of a component like so:

```
props: {
   // component-specific props ...
   ...sharedProps
}
```

then, when I try to access `this.exercise` inside of my component code, its inferred type is `Exercise|undefined` regardless of the fact that the corresponding prop has `required: true`.

[image]

In addition to just my IDE reporting the error, the build process also fails.

If I add the prop to the component code directly, that is without importing it, its type is correctly inferred as `Exercise`.

One more thing I noticed is that, if I provide a `default` to the prop, the issue goes away. My understanding, however, is that `required: true` should be enough for it to not be inferred to be an optional property.

Why does this happen if I import the props from an external file?

Comment: It always needs to be clarified how exactly you observe the behaviour of TS. It can behave differently in IDE and build process

Comment: Updated to include that information. I'm using eslint on vscode with volar.
The error gets reported in the IDE and npm run serve also fails when it encounters that line.

Comment: The one from `serve` should be considered a true one. This requires to investigate how type inference works in props. `required: true as const` or `sharedProps = {...} as const` can probably help here.

Answer (score 1):

@Estus Flask is right!

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from "vue";
type Exercise = {
  day: number
}
const sharedProps = {
  exercise: {
    type: Object as PropType<Exercise>,
    required: true as const,
  },
}

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    time: String,
    ...sharedProps
  }
})
</script>
<template>
  <h1>{{ exercise.day }}</h1>
</template>
```

[image: Snippet of correct inferred type]